# How to add a URL based on the username of the account

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

How do I supposed to create a url based on the username of the user? 
Can someone help me with the codes and the .htaccess configuration?
 
  **users.com/usernamehere**  
  If you want to view it on [Github](https://github.com/kirkcharlesniv/LoginAuthDB)

 If you want to view it on a [live website](http://login.prospekt.ml)

**Info**  
 If my user wants to view his page, he's gonna go to "*users.com/hisusername*". The link is gonna  **get**  his username and displays information about his account, and the  **.htaccess** gonna have the re-write rule (I guess?). Can someone help me with the code? 
  **Suggestion** 
 I've saw this in some tutorials but I can't follow them, so if the page have the tag of "`?username=usernamehere`", the user is gonna be redirected on the "`usernamehere`" page. 
 Example: The user is on "`users.com/profile.php?username=Stackoverflow`" and the user is gonna be redirected to: "`users.com/users/Stackoverflow`". Any chance of this gonna happen? Thanks and have a good day :)

Comment: Your Q needs more info.  Rephrase it to something more precise such as "What's the `.htaccess` rule needed to rewrite `URL_1` so it looks like `URL_2`", or "My user's page is at `URL_1`, but I want users to access it at `URL_2`; how can I do that with `.htaccess`?"

Comment: Ok thanks, gonna update it for more info :)

Answer (score 0):

> The user is on `users.com/profile.php?username=Stackoverflow` and the
>   user is gonna be redirected to: `users.com/users/Stackoverflow`. Any
>   chance of this gonna happen?

Note: Although this quote suggests the opposite, the answer below assumes that you want the user to enter `users.com/users/Stackoverflow` in the URL bar.

Place a file called `.htaccess` in your website's document root (the highest directory that contains your website files, typically called `public_html` or `www`)  Add the following rules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RedirectRule ^users/(.*)  /profile.php?username=$1  [END,NC]
```

The `NC` flag makes the comparison case-insensitive. Meaning that `users/Stack` and `USERS/Stack` will both be redirected. Remove it if you want a case-sensitive comparison

The `END` flag tells the server to stop looking for more redirect rules. Basically it ensures that `/profile.php?username=...` be the final destination of that request.

**addendum**

If you really want to redirect customers in the opposite directions, use this rule instead

```
RedirectRule ^profile.php?.*username=([^&$]+)  /users/$1  [END,NC]
```

This will probably cause you problems though if the path `/users/name` is not a real file

Comment: What does the END tag does?

Comment: see my update :-).  Also, I didn't use it here because it doesn't apply to your specific example, but I would add the `QSA` tag if your script relies on `$_GET` parameters. The `QSA` flag tells the server to pass along all query string arguments to the final scripts..  For example `users/joe?name=value` will become `profile.php?username=joe&name=value`.  Without `QSA` flag, the query arguments will be discarded

Comment: Oh thanks :) I'm only 13 y/o and starting here on PHP programming, sorry if I asking nonsense things since i'm a newbie here :D (and now my website is not responding).

Comment: No prob. Happy coding.

Comment: Does this work if the user entered the link directly instead of using the GET? example: Joe entered users.com/users/joe - instead of users.com/profile.php?username=joe

Comment: yes that rule will redirect `users/joe` to `profile.php?username=joe`

Comment: So when the user entered "users/joe" he will be redirected to "profile.php?username=joe"?

Comment: So, i've tried the code and it isn't working, try this: http://login.prospekt.ml/profile.php?username=astroXoom and see if it's gonna redirect you

Comment: M last comment was that `users/joe` would be redirected to `profile.php...`, not the opposite.  If your user enters `profile.php...` directly, then what do you want to see happen?

Comment: So here's it, it's like a profile page (like a Facebook account) that the users stats will be displayed. So the user gonna see his account. If the users entered "profile.php?username=theusername" he's gonna be redirected to users/hisusername (and your code doesn't work, please try to click the link that i've gave to you, and can we have chat in somewhere else? like Google Hangouts/gMail/Facebook?, thanks :) )

Comment: I know that my code doesn't work to do what you said. It's on purpose.  Usually, you don't want to redirect from `profile.php...` to the pretty URL.  It's the other way around: user enters `users/joe` and behind the scenes you redirect him to `profile.php...`.  However, if you're sure that you want the redirect direction you've been talking about, take another look at my answer. I've added at the bottom a rule that redirects users as you wish.